# What is a major node and a minor node?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

What is a `major node` and `minor node`?

I was reading [this article](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html) on files in the `/dev` directory and came across the description for `/dev/null`. According to the article, it says `/dev/null` is basiclly something you can write to and it will be lost.

So I can do something like this `dd if=story.txt of=/dev/null` for example and it will copy everything from `story.txt` to `/dev/null`

But the description also states: `It is a character device on major node 1 and minor node 3`

What is this? What do I learn by knowing this?

Comment: This question might get a better answer on another SE site. Like superuser or Unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the [makedev(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/major.3.html) function and [mknod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html) syscall. See also [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall.

Historically, devices are special kind of [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and the [major(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/major.3.html) number was defining the driver to be used inside the kernel, with the minor number identifying a device amongst several similar or related devices (think of one particular [tape device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive#History) amongst several ones).

Today things are more dynamic (and more complex) with systems like [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) & [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

In practice, you don't care (except when configuring `systemd` and coding driver kernel modules) about those details. You refer to a device by its name under `/dev/`